# How to show an image instead of a tab title for a field group?

Tags: entities

How can I show an image instead of the tab title of a field group?

Answer (score 2):

Each tab has a unique CSS id or class you can use CSS background-image and text-indent to hide the text of a field.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Text indent did the trick after I set it to -9999px. Still I have an issue. Apparently tabs don't have specific css class. All I have is .vertical-tab-button.first.selected and .vertical-tab-button. How do I set those classes? Thanks

Comment: [take a look at this](http://books.google.com/books?id=HejuTvJh2J4C&pg=PT263&lpg=PT263&dq=drupal+fieldgroup+css+selectors&source=bl&ots=9G6Ql-t8gA&sig=2OydxdxlRc9joavgRA_CU6ljXRI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I3kBUZDtDtLy2gXp_4CQDA&ved=0CFcQ6AEwAw), and use Firefox Firebug extension to see what selectors are assigned to your needed fields.